# Can I use some API call to invite User's Friends?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, invite

I want to invite facebook friends to my app. via some sort of API call  whether rest or PHP Sdk, so is there a way to do so. I know about multifriend selector in FBML but don't want that. Please tell that which API can be used to do so? Graph API or any other? I am using PHP so if you know some PHP API call then that is also good.

thanks in advance for assisting me.

Comment: This isn't meant to answer your question, but I can't tell you how annoying it is, in my opinion, when a friend of mine installs an app and it blindly invites all of their friends to install the app as well. I wish developers would leave the popularization of their app up to its users. :P

Comment: I am not doing it anonymously but to only invite people that he likes to invite but with API call separately than fbml.

Comment: Is this a app within Facebook?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Requests Dialog for invites. This will prompt the user for which friends to send a request/invite to. This is designed to work in iframe apps, no fbml required.

```
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/
```